# GEE hangs in a for loop using dates

Tags: google-earth-engine, for-loop

I want to have a loop on a date variable in Google Earth Engine, but it hangs and show me nothing when running just below simple code:

```
var aDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,12,21);
var bDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,12,31);
for(var d = aDate; d < bDate; d.advance(1,'day')){
  print(d);
}
```

I tried it in different forms and also via `while` loop, but it always hangs.
Any clue?

Comment: MSDN help for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) says you need to use 'new' or you get a string rather than a true date object. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Well, I am not much familiar with Javascript. I was just using the code style that I found in Google Earth Engine API and there is no use of 'new' codeword in their API for declaring and using variable of Date type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use for-loops for reasons described [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/getstarted#mapping-what-to-do-instead-of-a-for-loop) and [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server#looping) and [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging#avoid-mixing-client-functions-and-objects-with-server-functions-and-objects).  Do it this way:

```
var aDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,12,21);
var days = ee.List.sequence(1, 10);
var dates = days.map(function(d) {
  return aDate.advance(d, 'day');
});
print(dates);
```